# convert 4D array to json so it can be posted to php server

Tags: java, android, json

Am a newbie to Android(Java) and am working on an android application which requires sending data to a server.
How can i convert a 4D string array in Java to to JSON so that i can post it to a PHP server ?

Below is the code on how the 4D array is generated

```
    /// GET ALL USERS CONTACTS
public String[] fetchContacts(Context c) { 
    String phoneNumber = null; 
    String email = null; 
    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI; 
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID; 
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME; 
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER; 
    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI; 
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID; 
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER; 
    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID; 
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA; 
    //StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(); 
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver(); 
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);   

    List<String[][]> MasterArray = new ArrayList<String[][]>(); // Master Array

    String[] OneContactRow[] = new String[3][] ;

    String[] BigMasterArr = null ;

    List<String> displayname = new ArrayList<String>(); // Store all names
    List<String> PhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>(); // Store all phone numbers
    List<String> Emails = new ArrayList<String>(); // store all email address

    boolean hasContacts = false ;

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) { 

        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID )); 
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME )); 
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER ))); 
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {   
                hasContacts = true ;
                //output.append("\n First Name:" + name); 
                // Store name in first array
                displayname.add(name) ;
                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact 
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null); 
                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) { 
                    phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER)); 
                    // output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber); 
                    PhoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber)  ; // populate phone numbers array
                } 
                phoneCursor.close(); 
                // Query and loop for every email of the contact 
                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null); 

                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) { 

                    email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA)); 
                    //output.append("\nEmail:" + email); 
                    Emails.add(email)  ; // populate phone numbers array
                } 

                emailCursor.close(); 

                /// convert All name listArray to array
                String[] contactNamesArr = displayname.toArray(new String[displayname.size()]);

                /// convert All Phone listArray to array
                String[] PhoneNumbersArr = PhoneNumbers.toArray(new String[PhoneNumbers.size()]);

                /// convert All Email listArray to array
               String[] contactEmailArr = Emails.toArray(new String[Emails.size()]);

                // Add Everything to Each contacts array
                OneContactRow[0] = contactNamesArr ;
                OneContactRow[1] = PhoneNumbersArr ;
                OneContactRow[2] = contactEmailArr ;

                // Add everything to master array
                MasterArray.add(OneContactRow) ;  //>> NOW WE HAVE ONE ROW OF USER CONTACT

             // Empty all array lists Before Looping for next contact
                displayname.clear();
                PhoneNumbers.clear();
                Emails.clear();

            } 
            // Store Each Contact in master array

        } 

    } 

    if(hasContacts == true ){
         BigMasterArr = MasterArray.toArray(new String[MasterArray.size()]);
    }

    return BigMasterArr ; //<< 4D ARRAY
}
```

Comment: yes a 4 dimensional array

Comment: You should really create one or more classes instead of using arrays like that

Comment: @fge i am new to Java so that's the only way i know to fetch all contacts from a device and put them in an array so that i can post to a server. you have any better ideas ? it would be appreciated

Comment: I think everybody would feel better if you first create a decent structure for the data, e.g., just a List of Maps where each Map has "DisplayName" => name, "PhoneNumber" => number, "Email" => email. It seems you only store those 3 properties at least. That should be easily converted to JSON using a JSON library for Java. For example,   https://code.google.com/p/google-gson

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers like i mentioned, am new to java and am not very good with maps, any easier way to fetch all the device contact and send to a server will be well appreciated.

Comment: @UDcreate Maps are nothing more than a structure to associate keys with values, it's really not something you can be 'bad' at :) Just look at some examples and you'll be fine. Regardless, you could also check to see if any JSON libraries can convert primitive Arrays.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers am trying to use GSON i think they support multi-dimensional arrays